# How to speed up my neo4j instance

Tags: neo4j

I'm running neo4j version 2.2.5. I love all the CYPHER language, Python integration, ease of use, and very responsive user community.

I've developed a prototype of an application and am encountering some very poor performance times. I've read a lot of links related to performance tuning. I will attempt to outline my entire database here so that someone can provide guidance to me.

My machine is a MacBook Pro, 16GB of RAM, and 500GB SSD. It's very fast for everything else I do in Spark + Python + Hadoop. It's fast for Neo4j too, BUT when I get to like 2-4M nodes then it's insanely slow.

I've used both of these commands to start up neo4j, thinking they will help, and neither is that helpful:

```
./neo4j-community-2.2.5/bin/neo4j start -Xms512m -Xmx3g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
./neo4j-community-2.2.5/bin/neo4j start -Xms512m -Xmx3g -XX:+UseG1GC
```

My neo4j.properties file is as follows:

```
################################################################
# Neo4j
#
# neo4j.properties - database tuning parameters
#
################################################################

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# The amount of memory to use for mapping the store files, in bytes (or
# kilobytes with the 'k' suffix, megabytes with 'm' and gigabytes with 'g').
# If Neo4j is running on a dedicated server, then it is generally recommended
# to leave about 2-4 gigabytes for the operating system, give the JVM enough
# heap to hold all your transaction state and query context, and then leave the
# rest for the page cache.
# The default page cache memory assumes the machine is dedicated to running
# Neo4j, and is heuristically set to 75% of RAM minus the max Java heap size.
dbms.pagecache.memory=6g

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true".
#keep_logical_logs=7 days

# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#remote_shell_enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0 for all interfaces).
#remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
#remote_shell_port=1337

# The type of cache to use for nodes and relationships.
#cache_type=soft
```

To create my database from a fresh start, I first create these indexes, they are on all of my node types, and edges that I'm using.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (id:KnownIDType) ASSERT id.id_type_value IS UNIQUE; 
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:PerspectiveKey) ASSERT p.perspective_key IS UNIQUE;
CREATE INDEX ON :KnownIDType(id_type);
CREATE INDEX ON :KnownIDType(id_value);
CREATE INDEX ON :KNOWN_BY(StartDT);
CREATE INDEX ON :KNOWN_BY(EndDT);
CREATE INDEX ON :HAS_PERSPECTIVE(Country);
```

I have 8,601,880 nodes.

I run this query, and it takes 9 minutes.

```
MATCH (l:KnownIDType { id_type:'CodeType1' })<-[e1:KNOWN_BY]-(m:KnownIDType { id_type:'CodeType2' })-[e2:KNOWN_BY]->(n:KnownIDType)<-[e3:KNOWN_BY]-(o:KnownIDType { id_type:'CodeType3' })-[e4:KNOWN_BY]->(p:KnownIDType { id_type:'CodeType4' }), (n)-[e5:HAS_PERSPECTIVE]->(q:PerspectiveKey {perspective_key:100})
WHERE 1=1
AND l.id_type IN ['CodeType1']
AND m.id_type IN ['CodeType2']
AND n.id_type IN ['CodeTypeA', 'CodeTypeB', 'CodeTypeC']
AND o.id_type IN ['CodeType3']
AND p.id_type IN ['CodeType4']
AND 20131231 >= e1.StartDT and 20131231 < e1.EndDT
AND 20131231 >= e2.StartDT and 20131231 < e2.EndDT
AND 20131231 >= e3.StartDT and 20131231 < e3.EndDT
AND 20131231 >= e4.StartDT and 20131231 < e4.EndDT
WITH o, o.id_value as KnownIDValue, e5.Country as Country, count(distinct p.id_value) as ACount
WHERE AmbiguousCount > 1
RETURN 20131231 as AsOfDate, 'CodeType' as KnownIDType, 'ACount' as MetricName, count(ACount) as MetricValue
;
```

I'm looking for more like 15s or less response time. Like I do with < 1M nodes.

What would you suggest? I am happy to provide more information if you tell me what you need.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Have you profiled/explained your query? Can you see a particular step at which the number of DB hits increases?

Comment: try to read and apply: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/

Comment: how selective is your `id_type`
Prefix your query with PROFILE and share the result.

Comment: try to reduce cardinality in between your path.

Comment: you also span up a cartesian product with the second part of your query.

Comment: would you be able to share your db? drop me an email at michael at neo4j.com

Comment: Thanks Michael, you are a HUGE help with using neo4j, I'm very impressed by your commitment to it's success. Thanks so much for everything you do for the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas how to speed up your query:

- Don't use `IN` if there is only one element. Use `=`
- With a growing number of nodes, the index lookup will obviously take longer. Instead of having a single label with an indexed property, you could use the `id_type` property as label. Something like `(l:KnownIDTypeCode1)<-[e1:KNOWN_BY]-(m:KnownIDTypeCode2)`.
- Split up the query in two parts. First `MATCH` your `KNOWN_BY` path, then collect what you need using `WITH` and `MATCH` the `HAS_PERSPECTIVE` part.
- The range queries on the `StartDT` and `EndDT` property could be slow. Try to remove them to test if this slows down the query.
- Also, it looks like you could replace the `>=` and `<` with `=`, sind you use the same date everywhere.
- If you really have to filter date ranges a lot, it might help to implement it in your graph model. One option would be to use `Knownby` nodes instead of `KNOWN_BY` relationships and connect them to `Date` nodes.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Martin. My feedback/observations are as follow: 1) I removed IN clause and it's 5% faster - thank you and I will not use that for a single element array going forward 2) this is a very interesting point and one that I've been toying with for a while, I will re-factor my app and then re-run this and see if it's faster 3) I will try this out 4) I've removed them and it's not noticably faster ( 5)  i'll look into this one 6) that's a very useful concept - let me try #2 first and then #6 and see what that does. Thanks so much again

Answer (score 2):

First upgrade to version of 2.3, because it should improve performance - http://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-2-3-0/

Hint

- It doesn't make sense to use `IN` for array with one element.

Profile your query with `EXPLAIN` and `PROFILE`

- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html

Comment: I am trying this right now. I'll get back to you in a little while.

Comment: I just upgraded it and it didn't help ;( -- It still takes 8 minutes to run this query. Too long...

Answer (score 0):

Martin, your second recommendation, has sped up my matching paths to single digit seconds, I am grateful for your help. Thank you. While it involved a refactoring the design of my graph, and query patterns, it's improved the performance exponentially. I decided to create CodeType1, CodeType2, CodeType[N] as nodes labels, and minimized the use of node properties, except for keeping the temporality properties on the edges. Thank you again so much! Please let me know if there is anything I can do to help.